# Trabalhando com Turnos em Dimensão de Horas

Tags: banco-de-dados, lógica, business-intelligence

Estou estruturando um novo DataWarehouse que futuramente irá ser consumido em uma plataforma de BI.

Já criei algumas dimensões para meu banco de dados uma delas foi a de **Datas**, na qual eu quebro a data em diversos formatos para futura manipulação. 
 Atualmente estou criando a dimensão de **Horas** que por enquanto está no seguinte formato:

```
 HORA_COMPLETA | HORA | MINUTO | SEGUNDO | PERIODO   |TURNO
 10:01:25      | 10   | 01     | 25      | Manhã     | 1
 17:43:32      | 17   | 43     | 32      | Tarde     | 1
 23:12:13      | 23   | 12     | 13      | Noite     | 2
 03:07:46      | 03   | 07     | 46      | Madrugada | 2
 .
 .
 .
```

- Existem 2 turnos possíveis (6:00 até 18:00 'turno 1'  e 18:00 até 06:00 'turno 2' )

O problema que estou tendo é o seguinte:

Futuramente vou querer saber os resultador da equipe do **Turno 2** por dia. A questão é que esse turno (2) atravessa dois dias (a noite do dia 7/05 e a madrugada do dia 8/05 por exemplo), nesse caso o resultado do turno 2 seria a junção desses dois períodos que estão em dias diferentes .

A estrutura da tabela de data está resumidamente assim:

```
   DATA_COMPLETA | DIA | MES | ANO
   07/05/2018    | 07  | 05  | 2018
   08/05/2018    | 08  | 05  | 2018 
   09/05/2018    | 09  | 05  | 2018
   .
   .
   .
```

Existe alguma forma de colocar isso na tabela de forma a atender essa situação?

*Só para complementar, essas duas tabelas não se acessam diretamente ou seja outras tabelas é que utilizam esses dados.

Comment: Essa dimensão de datas que você se refere tem relação com o que? Marcação de ponto? De qualquer forma são duas dimensões que você se refere: uma é por data e outra por turno. Se um turno atravessa duas datas, você terá que ver por turno. Se quiser ver por data, verá o mesmo turno aparecendo duas vezes.

Comment: No caso se referem ao período para o cadastro de algumas fichas no sistema Rogério, a questão é que ao ver por turno a base está consideram a madrugada e a noite do dia 7 por exemplo. Não a noite do dia 7 e a madrugada do dia 8 como deveria ser